# Pandas: group dataframe by custom function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a tuple of strings. I would like to group by the length of the strings. This can be done with

```py
import pandas as pd

data = 'aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dd', 'eeee', 'ff'

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['string'])

def length(index):
    return len(df.at[index, 'string'])

for length, group in df.groupby(by=length):
    print(group)
    print('(length:', str(length) + ')', end='\n\n')
```

```
  string
1     bb
3     dd
5     ff
(length: 2)

  string
0    aaa
2    ccc
(length: 3)

  string
4   eeee
(length: 4)
```

Now my questions:

1. do I really need to create a function `len(df.at[index, column]` in order to group the single column dataframe by length?
2. is this the optimal way to group-by custom function? A comparison between this solution (applied to a file with 140,000 words) and a pure Python solution with dictionaries shows that this solution takes 32.5(!) seconds to run while the Python solution takes 0.95 seconds to run.

Answer (score 0):

pandas DataFrame and Series already have a `.hist()` method.
You can simply do,

```py
import pandas as pd

data = 'aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dd', 'eeee', 'ff'
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['password'])

df['password'].str.len().hist()
```

Or if not making a df is fine with you, (as your solution 1), then,

```py
pd.Series(data).str.len().hist()
```

Checkout [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.hist.html) on how you customize the plot

Comment: Sorry, my question is not about plotting but about grouping. I'll edit the intro to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

We have [series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) `groupby`

```
for x, y in df.groupby(df.string.str.len()):
    print(y)
    print('(length:', str(x) + ')', end='\n\n')

  string
1     bb
3     dd
5     ff
(length: 2)
  string
0    aaa
2    ccc
(length: 3)
  string
4   eeee
(length: 4)
```

Comment: Sorry, using Series instead of Dataframe doesn't make the group-by faster (question #2) nor answer question #1.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: This is actually a comment but put as an answer for proper format.

Ben's answer somewhat answer your question 1: No, you don't need to create the function in order to groupby. Not to mention your custom function can be slow since it calls `at` access every time. This can be seen by a performance comparison:

```
# random data
np.random.seed(1)
data= [''.join(np.random.choice(list('abcdefgh'),np.random.randint(5,10)) )
    for _ in range(100000)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['string'])

def length(index):
    return len(df.at[index, 'string'])

# Your solution:
%%time
x=0
for length, group in df.groupby(length):
    x+=length
# CPU times: user 451 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 451 ms
# Wall time: 450 ms


# Ben's solution
%%time
x=0
for x, y in df.groupby(df.string.str.len()):
    x+=length

# CPU times: user 35.5 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 35.5 ms
# Wall time: 34.2 ms
```

**Note** these two use simple function inside the `for` loop. In your code, `print` will be the bottleneck since printing to terminal is **always** slow. I highly doubt a pure Python grouping function can be as fast as Ben's solution. Please post that solution and I'm happy to learn that I am wrong on this.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I didn't read Ben's solution carefully enough. His and your reply actually do answer my two questions. Ben's `str.len()` of course only applies to vectorized functions. I'll post an update with a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Ben's and Quang Hoang's answers and building on them: I needed a generic group-rows-by-function solution (the mathematical term for that would be "equivalence classes"). One thing to consider is that not all functions have a "vectorized" equivalent like `len` and `pandas.Series.str.len`.

Solution:

```py
def groupby(df, projection=lambda x: x, label=0):  
    '''
    group dataframe into equivalence classes
    see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation
    '''
    return df.groupby(by=df.loc[:, label].apply(projection), sort=False)
```

Now using `groupby(df, len)` on the above mentioned file with 140,000 words takes 0.45 seconds instead 32.5 seconds. This means the pandas group-by solution is twice as fast as the pure Python solution using dictionaries. Thanks to Ben and Quang Hoang for their input.